# Setting varibable to saved value always gets true

Tags: javascript, checkbox, electron, boolean

I am working on a desktop application with electron, which means, that I am using javascript and other web tools. In this bit of code, I am trying to read a boolean from localStorage and writing it to the checked attribute of an HTML-checkbox:
`devtools = document.getElementById('dev-tools-checkbox');
console.log('The saved value: ' + localStorage.getItem('devtools'));
devtools.checked = localStorage.getItem('devtools');`

The strange thing is, that no matter what the console shows the logged value as, the checkbox always gets set to true. When reversing the input like this 
`devtools.checked = !localStorage.getItem('devtools');`
the value is always false. I have checked that the right value is set, and the logged value is correct.

When I set the following: `devtools.checked = false;` it correctly sets the value to false. Same with `devtools.checked = true`.

Any clue as to where the always true value is coming from would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information, just ask.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem()` returns a DOMString, so the test will always pass except when the item is not set (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

You should check if the item equals true instead:

`devtools.checked = localStorage.getItem('devtools') == 'true';`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN Documentation on `localStorage.setItem ()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem), you can only store elements of the type `DOMString` inside any `Storage` a User Agent (aka browser) offers. Thus, what you are retrieving is a string and since the HTML attribute `checked` on a checkbox does not need any input, it will be checked nonetheless.

Take this checkbox for example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="false" />
```

Although the `checked` attribute is set to `false`, the checkbox is checked. Thus, you need to first convert your string value you're retrieving from `localStorage` to a boolean. This can be done by using the following code:

```js
devtools = document.getElementById ('dev-tools-checkbox');
console.log ('The saved value: ' + localStorage.getItem('devtools'));
devtools.checked = localStorage.getItem('devtools') === "true";
```